# Show option only when currentState is empty

Tags: javascript

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1S_NhKkvGA) tutorial to make a text based adventure as my first real javaScript program. I'm a total beginner, but I figured that I could learn something from just throwing myself out there. My problem is that I want one of my options to show only when the character isn't carrying anything. This is my code:

```
id: 2,
    text:"You venture forth and soon appears a small village. The village seems to be holding a celebration. By the side of the road, you see a merchant.",
    options: [
        {
            text: "Trade the stone for a sword",
            requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.strangeStone,
            setState: { strangeStone: false, sword: true },
            nextText: 3
        },
        {
            text: "Trade the stone for some money",
            requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.strangeStone,
            setState: { strangeStone: false, someMoney: true },
            nextText: 3
        },
        {
            text: "You don't seem to have anything of value on you. The merchant ignores you",
            requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.undefined, //I have no idea what to write here
            nextText: 3
        },
```

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById("text")
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById("option-buttons")

let state = {} //Empty objects. Keeps track of what our character has on them//

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}

//Display whichever option we're on//
function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text //Makes descriptive text show?//
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    console.log("Removing stuff")
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild) /*removoes all options when options element has a first child*/
  }
  //textNode.forEach(element => console.log(element));
  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('btn') /*styles it properly css*/
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}

function showOption(option) {
  return option.requriedState == null || option.requriedState(state) //check if we have required state obejct = no required state
}

/*Take whatever option we select*/
function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState) //take state we have currently add everything from option setstate to it, ovverride anything thats already there.
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "On a bright moonlight night you're wandering thorugh an old forrest. Low hanging Wisterias brush agaisnt your face. Down the road you can see a strange stone glistering.",
    options: [{
        text: "Pick up the strange stone",
        setState: {
          strangeStone: true
        },
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: "Keep walking.",
        nextText: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "You venture forth and soon appears a small village. The village seems to be holding a celebration. By the side of the road, you see a merchant.",
    options: [{
        text: "Trade the stone for a sword",
        requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.strangeStone,
        setState: {
          strangeStone: false,
          sword: true
        },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: "Trade the stone for some money",
        requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.strangeStone,
        setState: {
          strangeStone: false,
          someMoney: true
        },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: "You don't seem to have anything of value on you. The merchant ignores you",
        requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.undefined, //Check if this can be null. Othervise remove required state
        //    setState: { strangeStone: false, someMoney: true },
        nextText: 3
      },
      // {
      //     text: "Keep walking",
      //     nextText: 3
      //  }
    ]

  }
]

/*Call function start game as soon as game has loaded. Starts game*/
startGame()
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

#text {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /*Stop it from jumping during hover*/
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Text Adventure</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <!--Where all the option buttons are stored-->
      <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here's a link](https://codepen.io/lennytriestocode/pen/JjXaEpZ) to a codepen (It's basically just the tutorial with some confused comments from me).

The first two options only show up if the character is currently carrying the object strangeStone. I want the last option to show up when the character is not carrying anything at all. How should one do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please send us your code so we can help you? 
the snippet is a bit difficult to adapt without context

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. We need to better understand what is `currentState` and what is `requiriedState` (sic). Try to incorporate their definitions in the snippet.

Comment: Hello and Sorry! Here's a link to a codepen with my code: https://codepen.io/lennytriestocode/pen/JjXaEpZ

Answer (score 2):

The option will show up when you return `true` from your `requriedState`, otherwise, if you return false, it won't show up. With that in mind, you want your function to return a value of `false` when you have either the strange stone [or (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) some money (this way it won't appear). This logic can be represented like so:

```
requriedState: (currentState) => !(currentState.strangeStone || currentState.someMoney)
```

The above function will return a value of `false` when either of the strangeStone or someMoney are true. This is because the `||` (or) operator will return the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value it finds. This value is then negated (ie: flipped - so true becomes false and false because true) using the [NOT operator `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT). So, the only time it will return `true` is when both `strangeStone` and `someMoney` are both `false` (ie: you are not carrying anything).

See example below:

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById("text")
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById("option-buttons")

let state = {} //Empty objects. Keeps track of what our character has on them//

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}

//Display whichever option we're on//
function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text //Makes descriptive text show?//
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    console.log("Removing stuff")
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild) /*removoes all options when options element has a first child*/
  }
  //textNode.forEach(element => console.log(element));
  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('btn') /*styles it properly css*/
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}

function showOption(option) {
  return option.requriedState == null || option.requriedState(state) //check if we have required state obejct = no required state
}

/*Take whatever option we select*/
function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState) //take state we have currently add everything from option setstate to it, ovverride anything thats already there.
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "On a bright moonlight night you're wandering thorugh an old forrest. Low hanging Wisterias brush agaisnt your face. Down the road you can see a strange stone glistering.",
    options: [{
        text: "Pick up the strange stone",
        setState: {
          strangeStone: true
        },
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: "Keep walking.",
        nextText: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "You venture forth and soon appears a small village. The village seems to be holding a celebration. By the side of the road, you see a merchant.",
    options: [{
        text: "Trade the stone for a sword",
        requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.strangeStone,
        setState: {
          strangeStone: false,
          sword: true
        },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: "Trade the stone for some money",
        requriedState: (currentState) => currentState.strangeStone,
        setState: {
          strangeStone: false,
          someMoney: true
        },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: "You don't seem to have anything of value on you. The merchant ignores you",
        requriedState: (currentState) => !(currentState.strangeStone || currentState.someMoney), //Check if this can be null. Othervise remove required state
        //    setState: { strangeStone: false, someMoney: true },
        nextText: 3
      },
      // {
      //     text: "Keep walking",
      //     nextText: 3
      //  }
    ]

  }
]

/*Call function start game as soon as game has loaded. Starts game*/
startGame()
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

#text {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /*Stop it from jumping during hover*/
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Text Adventure</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <!--Where all the option buttons are stored-->
      <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: assuming currentState.empty doesn't exists

Comment: @DaemonPainter yeah, I'm assuming that when OP says "the character isn't carrying anything" they mean that both the states in the `currentState` are false. I couldn't find a mention of an `empty` state in the Codepen OP added in either.